# Right click on ListBox open ToolStripMenu but doesn't select any item

Tags: vb.net, select, listbox, right-click

I have a `ListBox` containing full path and a `ToolStripMenu` to choose Open File or Show File in Folder.

The issue is: I need to Left Click on a `ListBoxItem` before Right Click to select the file I need to show in folder.
If I don't do this I get `NullReferenceException` because no item is selected.

How can I get selected the item Right Clicked?

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub ShowInFolderToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ShowInFolderToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Try
        If DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).GetCurrentParent,  _
            ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl.GetType Is GetType(ListBox) Then

            Shell("explorer /select, " & DirectCast(DirectCast(DirectCast(sender,  _
                  ToolStripMenuItem).GetCurrentParent, ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl,  _
                  ListBox).SelectedItem.ToString, AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Just another question... Why the below code doesn't work but doesn't give error and show me document folder?

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select" & DirectCast(DirectCast(DirectCast(sender,  _
    ToolStripMenuItem).GetCurrentParent, ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl,  _
    ListBox).SelectedItem.ToString)
```

Comment: You could check if there is a selected item at the start

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, I know this. But could be selected the 1st item and right clicked the 3rd item and so could be shown the wrong file.

Comment: @Plutonix I solved, but I'm still open to better solutions ;)

Answer (score 0):

Solved adding MouseDown event:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MouseDown
    Try
        DirectCast(sender, ListBox).SelectedIndex = DirectCast(sender, ListBox).IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```